# ObjectOutputStream/Input Serializable in JAVA

Tags: java, serializable

i am working with `ObjectOutputStream` to save my object to a `.dat` file.
My problem is, that if i CHANGE source code of my object (for example i add ONE method(getter)) the 
input stream cannot load data and tell me a error about `Serializable`:
It is possible to solve this problem? I must generate new `.dat` file everytime after if i change my source code.

Using this method:
(**DONT LOOK AT THE OBJECT TYPE-return value**)
SAVE

```
public void saveToFile(HeaderOfMapTeachStructure hm, String nameOfFile) {
    try (ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream(nameOfFile + "." + this.TYPE_OF_FILE))) {
        os.writeObject(hm);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }
}
```

LOAD

```
public MapStandard loadFromFileMS(String nameOfFile) {
    MapStandard hm = null;
    InputStream inputStreaminputStream
            = getClass().getClassLoader().
            getResourceAsStream("data/" + nameOfFile + ".data");
    try {
        try (ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(inputStreaminputStream)) {
            hm = (MapStandard) is.readObject();
        }
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }
    return hm;
}
```

ERROR IS:

```
Error: java.io.InvalidClassException: MapVerb.RealVerb; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -887510662644221872, local class serialVersionUID = 7992494764692933500
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It is possible to solve this problem?

Yes. The reason the serialization breaks is because the generated version number changes. If you specify this explicitly, it won't be generated, and you'll be in control of versioning. That means you need to be careful though - if you change the fields which are in the object, or the *meaning* of those fields, you'll need to remember to change the version number yourself.

You specify the serialization version like this:

```
// It doesn't have to be constant, but that's fairly common.
private static final long serialVersionUID = ...; // Some constant
```

See the documentation for [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) for more information.

You might also want to consider using alternative approaches for storing data - the default binary serialization in Java is fairly brittle. There are lots of alternatives - text-based formats such as XML, JSON or YAML, or binary formats such as Protocol Buffers or Thrift.